# Javascript - function / closure variable scope - where is the variable defined?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am working on my worker remote method invocation and class instantiation and I was doing some eval research with closures. I came with the code bellow which I really like and I'll use it, but don't really understand why it works and how it works. Actually, I don't understand where the 'a' variable is stored and also where the name of it is stored as I can access it inside the function or by calling evals. Also, I would like to know what is its life cycle and when it will get destroyed. Is it a hack of JS engine or is it valid usage? I tested with IE10, IE11, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, Safari mobile... it works everywhere. I am so curious.

https://jsfiddle.net/bykwm1h3/2/

```
function scope(params) {
    if (params) {
        a = params;
    } else {
        console.log(a);   
    }   
}

function evalInScope(code) {
    eval.call(this, code)
}

// define variable - where is it defined?? definitely in the scope of the function as it is accessible there but, who really holds its instance?
evalInScope.call(scope, "var a;");

// setup variable values
scope([1,2,3]);

// print it out
evalInScope.call(scope, "console.log(a)");

// or print it out
scope();
```

Comment: There is no need, whatsoever, to use `eval` to handle scoping your variables.

Comment: I need to generate code dynamically as I am passing it to worker and instancing it there. And I need to keep the scope valid i.e for class properties which refers to another classes.

Comment: Needing to generate code dynamically doesn't mean you need `eval` to handle scope. You might want to post a separate question outlining what you want to do and asking how to do it without `eval`.

Comment: Believe me, I am playing around that for 4 days. I know what I am talking about ;)

Comment: This is a heavy X,Y question -- you post a question, but without context, so the only answer you'll get is related to your presumed answer, and nobody can give you a better methodology

Comment: With respect, I suspect that if you do post that question I mentioned, you'll learn something new. :-) I'd love to see the question, personally; if you really need to use `eval` for this (and I don't think you do), I'm always keen to know more.

Comment: Actually, after 3 days of elaborating how to get it done I have bit headache :D

Comment: @Fis: No, I'd like to see the question. :-) (Dashing off now in any case.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Ok. My goal actually is:

Have code generated with typescript, with namespaces, whatever.
I need to get it, pass it over messaging and instantiate it in worker in the totally same way it is on the main ui thread side. Including the prototype tree. This works well now. But when I have a class in which constructor I want to create another deployed class it gives me reference error. Its hard to describe it in few lines because there is quiet a lot of code behind it including transfer protocols, interfaces, router, whatever.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder its impossible to achieve as it is a complex problem. It would require decompile namespaces and all anonymous functions creating namespaces. I wanted to have it "clever" too much. I'll keep it as it is now so just "decompiling" the class prototype tree, passing it over the something I call "RIB" - remote invocation bus, instantiate it in worker, create proxy in main-ui and use my RMI to invoke methods. This works pretty well although it is limiting to do advanced things.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder but nevermind, I have another functionality to load libraries to worker so more complex requirements can be achieved in a different way ;)

if you are interested, check:
https://github.com/atomsoftwarestudios/AjsDev/tree/master/Ajs.Lib.ts
https://github.com/atomsoftwarestudios/AjsDev/tree/master/Ajs.WebWorker
https://github.com/atomsoftwarestudios/AjsDev/tree/master/Ajs/DistributedServices

bit complex and quiet a lot of code ;)

also you can check this:
https://ajsfw.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `a` is a global variable, because you're doing an *indirect `eval`*. When you do indirect `eval`, the code you pass `eval` is evaluated at global scope. `var` at global scope creates global variables.

The more canonical way to do indirect eval is either to use a variable:

```
var x = eval;
x("code here");
```

or use the comma operator:

```
(0, eval)("code here");
```

*Direct* eval (`eval("code here")`) evaluates the code you pass it within the scope in which the `eval` call appears.

And yes: This business of direct vs. indirect `eval` is confusing, surprising, and not consistent with how other functions work. It wasn't designed, it grew and was codified. :-)

If your goal was to evaluate the code within the `scope` function, that's not what that code does. To do that, you'd use `eval` within `scope`:

```
function scope(code) {
    eval(code);
}
```

---

You can prove to yourself `a` is a global by seeing if it ended up as a property on the global object, which we can access via the `window` global on browsers:

```js
function scope(params) {
    if (params) {
        a = params;
    } else {
        console.log(a);   
    }   
}

function evalInScope(code) {
    eval.call(this, code)
}

console.log("a in window?", "a" in window); // false
evalInScope.call(scope, "var a;");
console.log("a in window?", "a" in window); // true
```

Comment: No, it is not. It is not accessible globally. I made sure